# How would one Initialize "a" ,which is an array, in the function InitializeArray , C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have another assignment and its stumping me. I have to set up functions so the professor can test them all together. He will erase my main function and create his own, so he leaves us to set up the functionality.

These are the instructions for the initialization :

```
 void InitializeArray(int a[], int arraySize);
 //  a: the array that you want to initialize
 //  arraySize: The number of elements to put in the array
 //  returns: nothing
```

This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int a[ARRAY_SIZE];
    InitializeArray(a, ARRAY_SIZE);   // This is to test my functions,
    std::cout << "Initial Array= ";   // InitializeArray and printArray.
    PrintArray(a, ARRAY_SIZE);
}

void SeedRand(int x)
{
    srand(x);   // Seed the random number generator
}

void InitializeArray(int a[], int arraySize)
{
    arraySize = 10;
    a[arraySize] = { 1 + rand() % 100 };
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        // Develop an algorithm that inserts random numbers
        // between 1 and 100 into a[]
        // hint: use rand()
}

void PrintArray(int a[], int arraySize)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < arraySize; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << a[n] << " ";
    }
    // print the array using cout
    // leave 1 space in-between each integer
    // Example: if the array holds { 1, 2, 3 }
    // This function should print: 1 2 3 
    // It is ok to have a dangling space at the end
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You're screwed my friend.  You lost me at `a[arraySize]`

Comment: How to initialize the array "a" within the function InitializeArray

Comment: @ProjectAnsem `a[arraySize]`

Comment: `arraySize = 10;     a[arraySize] = { 1 + rand() % 100 };` Do you really know what you are doing here?

Comment: @AdrianShum, there's no way she/he does.   Halfway through the semester, no less.

Comment: No thats why Im asking for help, this is my first programming class.

Comment: @ProjectAnsem I can see you are new to programming but obviously you haven't done your previous homework right. You are now learning array but you don't even know the impact of changing the input parameter of function by `arraySize = 10; ` ?  New to programming is not an excuse dude

Comment: @ProjectAnsem we've all been insulted by people on here.  Don't take it personally.  The tough criticism, I found, actually makes me learn better.  As a testament, you can bet your ass that I will never forget to balance my `new` and `delete` calls.

Comment: @TriHard8 I have never meant to insult him (or anyone) actually  :P

Comment: @AdrianShum noone `means` it as an insult.  Maybe that was a poor choice of a word.  Public shaming perhaps?  Slight bit of hazing to acclimate people to the ways of SO?

Comment: I like your word 'hazing to acclimate'  (thumb up)  (Although my original intention is just to criticize OP about something he should have known he have done wrong  :P )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is strange and wrong

```
void InitializeArray(int a[], int arraySize)
{
 arraySize = 10;
 a[arraySize] = { 1 + rand() % 100 };
 for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
```

the arraySize is set outisde the function but you assign it 10 inside, why? The point of supplying the size to the function is for the function to know the size.

when you initialize the array you need to loop through each element and assign it a value, with (which anyway has wrong syntax)

```
a[arraySize] = { 1 + rand() % 100 };
```

you are actually accessing an element outside the array, the valid indices are `0..arraySize-1`.

So to initialize each element write something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
{
  a[i] = 1 + rand()% 100;
}
```

Comment: Way too kind for someone with 24k rep.

Comment: personally i find the tone here at SO is a bit elitistic at times, better for the soul to be a bit forgiving :-)

Comment: @CyberSpock  thank you for actually assisting as well as not waste your time with useless banter! I appreciate the help and condor.